# edit my email when i login as guest and go to home page in rails using spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, spree

- I select an item and go to checkout
- it will show login page.
- In that page if, I entered as guest it will go to address page.
- I leave checkout and go to the home page
- I return to checkout

it is rendering address page not login page again.

Answer (score 0):

You are back in address because you are still logged in as a guest.

If you don't want to be:

- then logout
- add to your cart
- go to checkout again

it will then send you to the login page.